# Crystal Reports Selection Formula Crystal Syntax - - value not in a field or value in an array

Tags: arrays, string, crystal-reports, selection

I want exclusions in my record selections but not having success with my not “in” statement.

This statement works

`and not ({Table.Field} startswith ["ABC","123"])  //works when values start with items in the array`

But this statement seems to be ignored although the values are in the field

`and not ({Table.Field} in ["ABC","123"])  // doesn’t work when values are anywhere in the field`

This statement doesn’t work either (no array, but value is in the field:

`and not ({Table.Field} in "ABC”)  // doesn’t work either`

The statements are part of multiple selection and exclusions.
Could someone tell me how to get the "not in array" selection working in Crystal syntax please?  I'm sure its something very simple that I keep overlooking.  Text upper/lower case is not the problem.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for InStr function, which returns the place where a string is found in another string, if it's found, 0 otherwise. Your selection formula would look like this then:

```
Not (InStr({Table.Field}, 'ABC') > 0)
```

Caveat: When using CR functions for filtering, there's a risk that CR can't delegate filtering to the db backend which would lead to poor performance under some circumstances.

Edit: Example to perform the check with every string in an array - can be done within the record selection formula:

```
StringVar Array stringarray := ["ABC", "123"];
Local NumberVar i;
Local BooleanVar atLeastOneStringFound;
atLeastOneStringFound := false;
For i := 1 To Count(stringarray) Do (
    If InStr({Table.Field}, stringarray[i]) > 0 
    Then atLeastOneStringFound := true;
);
Not atLeastOneStringFound;
```

Comment: Hi @MWeber,
Thanks.  No, I’m not wanting to find the location of the string in the field.  If the sought string is anywhere in the field, I want to exclude that record from the selection.  Locating the position in the field adds another layer of complexity to the selection formula that I want to avoid it as there are already lots of selection inclusion and exclusion criteria.  We have an array of strings and it doesn’t matter where in the field they are located.  If any of the strings exist in the field, we don’t want the record.

Comment: Hi @JRo, that's exactly what the above expression does => if the string is found in the other one, the result of InStr would be greater than zero. Afaik there's no built-in regex support in CR's. Surely available as addon from 3rd party vendors, but imo that path adds more complexity overall.

Comment: @JRo, regarding "array of strings": you can just loop through the array, perform the check for every item and act accordingly then. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked perfectly for the record selection. I truly appreciate your help.  Following on from that - as I believe it would use similar function and logic except there are additional conditions involved - I want to create a formula extracting dates that might be in a text field that could be formatted DDMMYY, DDMMYYYY, DD/MM/YY or DD/MM/YYYY.  How is the best way to write it please?   I have seen a post that searched for the"/" and moved back 2 char and then selected the next x characters but as I have 4 likely scenarios I'm not sure the best way to write it.

Comment: Hi @JRo, I believe this site's rules would require you to ask a new SO question for this additional problem.

Comment: Aaahh sorry, and thank you. Will do it as a new question.  Thanks so much for your help.